# Pentaho Flow Input->Output->Input not working

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a Table Input step that retrieves some data form a table A.

Data is passed to an Insert/Update step to a table B.  For each row inserted/updated, I want to execute another Table Input on table C using one of the field values passed from the Insert/Update in table B step.

---  ---  --- ...

The problems?

1) When I link the Insert/Update step to a Table Input step, then right click the Input step to verify the inputs, it tells me no input fields.

<1 table input> --- <2 input/update> --- <3 table input>  (no can see input fields in step 3)

2) When I run the step anyway, it is trying to map the 14 fields from the Insert/UPdate step into JDBC place holders.  I only need one field from previous step

<1 table input> --- <2 input/update> --- <3 table input>  (tries to find 14 JDBC placeholders in step 3, only need one))

3) Every time I try to limit the output from the  Insert/Update step, it shows all fields.  I remove the ones I don't want, but no impact.

<1 table input> --- <2 input/update> --- <3 table input>  (can't limit the outfields from step 2)

4) If I insert a select value step between the two, the that steps does see the output from the Insert step as input, and now the Table Input step CAN see the input fields from the previous step.  HOWEVR, the select value step fails as it is expecting a rowset from Insert/Update step.

<1 table input> --- <2 input/update> --- <3 select value> --- <4 table input> (everything looks right, can see the right fields in the cfg, but fails as step 3 is looking for rowset)

The goal?  I am migrating a set of parent records from DB1 to DB2, then I want to use the list of ids from that parent set as input to migrate the child records as part of the stream.

Using Pentaho 7.1

Comment: Let me rephrase your need, forgetting about the problems for now, and tell me if I am wrong. You have an input table that you want to copy (without loosing previous data in the target table), and, for each of the records added in the table, you will fetch the record with the same in an other table to add them in another table.

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  Inserting the "select values" was the solution but I forgot to reset the step after it to get data from the "select value" step, so it was still trying to get data from the step before that.